# How to Identify the App type on Office store?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

I want to know that which type of app I am using from `Office Store`.

If I have installed an App from `Office store`, That app is Provider Hosted or SharePoint hosted.

**Is there any way to recognize the type of app published to the office store?**

Can anyone help me to solve this?
Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Please stop making non-changes to your post to make it bounce up to the top again..

Comment: What to do when no one is answering.? And what should it make difference?

Comment: If someone knows the answer, or is interested in investigating it, they will answer you. If not, then bad luck I guess :)

Comment: To answer your question, if you want to improve the chances of getting an answer, review your question to see if it can be improved (by genuine editing - see the FAQ for how to ask a good question), or create a bounty on the question. Good luck. [mod]